# Unity3D Photon Call A Method Before Local Player Disconnected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I have a method which works pretty well when calling somewhere else or calling by ui buttons.

**I'm having this issue:**
I need to call this method just before when **local player disconnected.**

If i use "OnPhotonPlayerDisconnected()" it doesn't work properly because it is calling from remote player, not locally.

I also tested "OnLeftRoom()" method but it doesn't even calling.

My method here:

```
public void ReleaseSlot()
{
    Slots[slotIndex] = true;
    Hashtable SlotManagerHashtable = new Hashtable();
    SlotManagerHashtable.Add("teamslot" + slotIndex.ToString(), false);
    PhotonNetwork.room.SetCustomProperties(SlotManagerHashtable, null, false);
    alreadyJoined = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried also OnDisconnectedFromPhoton?

Comment: I tried just before, method doesn't even calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PUN callback method for the **local** client's disconnection from all Photon servers is `OnDisconnectedFromPhoton()`.
If this method is called then the **local** client needs to reconnect to Photon servers first in order to be able to call any other operation.

The PUN callback method for when the **local** client has left the room is `OnLeftRoom()`. If this method is called then the **local** client can no longer call any operations inside the room like `SetProperties` which is what you are trying to do via `PhotonNetwork.room.SetCustomProperties`.

The PUN callback method for when a **remote** client has left the room is `OnPhotonPlayerDisconnected(PhotonPlayer player)`.

The logic you have in `ReleaseSlot` cannot be executed after `OnDisconnectedFromPhoton()` or `OnLeftRoom()`. On the other hand, if you want to call this just before a player decides to leave the room explicitly you will not be handling the cases of unexpected disconnects where the player leaves the room involuntarily.

So you need to change the way you free team slots (or update score?!) when a player leaves the room. You need to do this from one of the remaining players, preferably the master client. However, when the room becomes empty after master client leaving, no one will be left to call `ReleaseSlot`. Of course, this is in case this situation needs to be handled.

So `OnPhotonPlayerDisconnected` is a good candidate.

And in case you missed it, my colleague Tobias already posted [a comment on the discussion -identical to this one- that you started on Photon's official forum](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/46087/#Comment_46087).

Comment: You need to identify the slot number from the player who left (`otherPlayer`) in `OnPhotonPlayerDisconnected(PhotonPlayer otherPayer)` which is triggered via Unity's mono messages, so just put it on any MonoBehaviour on any GameObject like the other callbacks. So this should be added to each player yes but do not call ` PhotonNetwork.room.SetCustomProperties` only if `PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient` is `true`. Choosing to do this from MasterClient only has one purpose: is to do it from a single client instead of all clients.